# Toggling Phantom In Macros (plain TeX)

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I am using plain TeX / pdfTeX.

Is there a way to build a set of macros, say `\showOn` / `\showOff`, such that

1. I can nest them
2. for a given piece of text, it "looks up the parse tree", find the first `\showOn`/`\showOff` parent, and gets displayed if and only if it's on?

For example:

```
Cat \showOff { dog \showOn {red \showOff {blue} green } superman} wonderwoman
```

Would result in:

```
Cat [spacing for dog] red [spacing for blue] green [spacing for superman] wonderwoman
```

So, I know that I can do the spacing without display part through using phantom - however, is there any way to turn phantom on/off in a nested manner?

Right now, I have:

```
\def\showOn#1{{#1}}
\def\showOff#2{\phantom{#2}}
\showOff {\showOn {foo}}
\bye
```

However, this clearly fails the nesting since
    `\showOff {\showOn {foo}}` will NOT output `foo`.

### Edit:

My fault for not including this earlier. Color changing does not work. The document changes colors all over the place (in pdfTeX).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: What do you want in a minimum working example? I have no idea how to create this in the first place. What part of my description is not clear?

Comment: @PeterGrill A MWE here would be in plain :-)

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to make the question easier to answer?

Comment: @JosephWright: Could add the `\def\showOff{}
\def\showOn{}` and `\bye`.  Not everyone uses plain TeX so it takes time to get to this point (well at least for me).

Comment: Do you change the colors of both background and foregorund, or only foreground?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An answer which does not rely on colors and allows verbatim text.

```
\catcode 64 11
\newif\if@inSO@
\def\ShowOff{\afterassignment\ShowOff@\setbox\z@\hbox}
\def\ShowOff@{\@inSO@true\aftergroup\ShowOff@@}
\def\ShowOff@@{\hskip\wd\z@}
\def\ShowOn{\if@inSO@\expandafter\ShowOn@\fi}
\def\ShowOn@#{\egroup\bgroup\aftergroup\ShowOn@@\let\next= }
\def\ShowOn@@{\ShowOff\bgroup}
\catcode 64 12

abcdefghijklmnop
coffin

abc\ShowOff{defg\ShowOn{hi\ShowOff{jk}lm}n}op
\ShowOn{co\ShowOff{f\ShowOn{f}i}n}

\end
```

How does `\phantom` work? It stores the text in a box, then creates an empty box with the same width, height and depth. In a similar way, I'll collect the text that should be hidden in box 0, and produce a horizontal space of the same width as that box. All text that is to be displayed is typeset directly.

Let us analyse for example `\ShowOff{abc}` First, it becomes

```
\afterassignment\ShowOff@ \setbox\z@\hbox{abc}
```

TeX remembers `\ShowOff@` for use after the next assignment, namely `\setbox`. The placement of the "after assignment" token in the case of `\setbox` is a little bit tricky; in our case it ends up after the opening brace following `\hbox`. Ignore `\@inSO@true` for the moment. `\aftergroup\ShowOff@@` will place `\ShowOff@@` as soon as the box that is being build ends. This macro, in turn, inserts a horizontal skip of the size of the box.

Now, `\ShowOn` cancels this hiding by ending the box of `\ShowOff` early, namely with the `\egroup` in `\ShowOn@`. The horizontal skip is then inserted there. We can then typeset the argument of `\ShowOn`, and resume hiding afterwards. I could have defined `\def\ShowOn@#1{\egroup#1\ShowOff\bgroup}`, but this grabs the argument early, forbidding verbatim. Instead, I used `\aftergroup` again: the argument of `\ShowOn` comes as a group, `{...}`. Somehow, we want to insert `\aftergroup\ShowOn@@` after the opening brace. Open a brace (`\bgroup`), and remove the one that the user put (`\let\next=`).

I still have to explain the `@inSO@` switch. If `\ShowOn` appears outside any `\ShowOff` command, it should just do nothing to its argument. Otherwise, it acts as described in the previous paragraph.

EDIT: I tried to add support for math mode below (didn't incorporate it above because the macros become ugly).

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\ShowOff
  {%
    \v@true\h@true
    \ifmmode
      \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\ShowOff@math
    \else
      \afterassignment\ShowOff@\setbox\z@\hbox
    \fi
  }
\def\ShowOff@{\let\ShowOn\ShowOn@\aftergroup\finph@nt}
\long\def\ShowOff@math#1{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox\bgroup$\m@th #1%
  \bgroup
    \aftergroup\ShowOff@math@
    \long\def\ShowOn##1{\egroup##1\ShowOff@math#1\bgroup}%
    \let\next= }
\def\ShowOff@math@{$\egroup\finph@nt}
\let\ShowOn\relax
\def\ShowOn@#{\egroup\bgroup\aftergroup\ShowOn@@\let\next= }
\def\ShowOn@@{\ShowOff\bgroup}
\catcode`@=12

% Tests.
$abcdefg^h_{ijkl}mnop$ $co^{ffi}n$

$abc\ShowOff{defg\ShowOn{^h_{i\ShowOff{jk}l}m}n}op$
$\ShowOn{co^{\ShowOff{f\ShowOn{f}i}}n}$

abcdefghijklmnop coffin

abc\ShowOff{defg\ShowOn{hi\ShowOff{jk}lm}n}op
\ShowOn{co\ShowOff{f\ShowOn{f}i}n}

\bye
```

Comment: Wow.  Nice job using `#{`, too.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: It's 1:22am here. I was about to go to sleep. But this looks too cool to not read and understand.

Comment: So I'm reading page 279 of Knuth's TexBook. Your \afterassignment\ShowOff@ \setbox\z@\hbox{abc} becomes: \setbox\z@\hbox{\ShowOff@ abc} <-- is this correct?

Comment: Two more requests: (1) how can I change the \hskip\wd\z@ so it does both width, height & depth. (2) Right now, if I use \showOff within math mode, it breaks, i.e. $\ShowOff{\sum_{i=1}^n}$ results in compile error for me. How do I fix this? -- Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, your placement of the after-assignment token is correct (although TeX only inserts it when it has already read the `\setbox\z@\hbox{` part). (1) can be done with `\v@true\h@true\finph@nt` (try `\show\finph@nt` to see what that macro does). (2) is much trickier. Perhaps some trick with `\mathpalette` could work.

Comment: I'm not happy with my solution for math. It seems to work in simple cases, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
\input color
\def\showOn#1{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\def\showOff#1{\textcolor{white}{#1}} 
Cat \showOff { dog \showOn {red \showOff {blue} green } superman} wonderwoman
\bye
```

*Update*

Here is the solution that does not assume the text is black.  It assumes, however, that the background is white.  Also, any explicit color change inside `\showOff` makes the text visible.

```
\input color
\catcode`\@=11
\newif\ifinside@showoff
\def\showOff#1{\textcolor{white}{\inside@showofftrue#1}}
\def\showOn#1{\ifinside@showoff
  \bgroup\inside@showofffalse\reset@color#1\egroup\color{white}%
  \else#1\fi}
\color{green} Cat \showOff { dog \showOn {\textcolor{red}{red}
\showOff {blue} green } superman} wonderwoman 
\bye
```

Comment: The OP is using plain TeX, not LaTeX.

Comment: My fault for not mentioning the document uses pdf's color changing abilities; so toggling to black/white won't work.

Comment: (Sorry for not mentioning the fact I was using pdftex's color changing abilities earlier.)

Comment: Clever, but this also produces the `green` and `wonderwoman` in white.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks - I've changed my answer

Comment: @PeterGrill I prefer `\showOn|Off` to be declarations.  Commands could be done with `\def\showOn#1{\textcolor{black}{#1}}` etc.